# True Search and Discover from Wikipedia api

Tags: api, mediawiki, wikipedia, wikipedia-api, mediawiki-api

I have a string to search "founder of google"

I use this request link: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=search&format=json&srwhat=text&rawcontinue&srprop=sectiontitle&srsearch=founder%20of%20google

But it returns

---

```
{
   "query-continue":{
      "search":{
         "sroffset":10
      }
   },
   "query":{
      "searchinfo":{
         "totalhits":14577
      },
      "search":[
         {
            "ns":0,
            "title":"Lars Rasmussen (software developer)"
         },
         {
            "ns":0,
            "title":"Wirth's law"
         },
         {
            "ns":0,
            "title":"Brin"
         },
         {
            "ns":0,
            "title":"H\u00e9ctor Garc\u00eda-Molina"
         },
         {
            "ns":0,
            "title":"Chris Wetherell"
         },
         {
            "ns":0,
            "title":"Forbes list of The World's Most Powerful People"
         },
         {
            "ns":0,
            "title":"Tamil American"
         },
         {
            "ns":0,
            "title":"Lars Rasmussen"
         },
         {
            "ns":0,
            "title":"List of Jewish American computer scientists"
         },
         {
            "ns":0,
            "title":"Larry"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

---

But I want only these two true results:

```
{
   "ns":0,
   "title":"Brin"
},
{
   "ns":0,
   "title":"Larry"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(1) - https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbsearchentities&search= google &language=en&type=item&format=json

(2) - https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbsearchentities&search= founder &language=en&type=property&format=json

(3) - https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbgetclaims&entity={id of 1st link}&property={id of 2nd link}&format=json

(4) - https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbgetentities&ids={ numeric-id of 3rd link }&languages=en&format=json&props=labels|descriptions|aliases
```

Answer (score 1):

The Wikipedia page [Lars Rasmussen (software developer)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lars_Rasmussen_%28software_developer%29) starts with the following paragraph (**emphasis** mine):

> "Lars Eilstrup Rasmussen is a Danish-born<sup>[1]</sup> computer scientist, software developer, and co-**founder of Google** Maps."

Therefore, it's a perfectly valid result of your search query.  So are all the other pages it returns, too.  For example, the article on [Wirth's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wirth's_law) reads:

> "The law was restated in 2009 and attributed to Larry Page, founder of Google."

and the article on [Héctor García-Molina](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%A9ctor_Garc%C3%ADa-Molina) contains the sentence:

> "He was advisor to Sergey Brin, the founder of Google, from 1993 to 1997 when he was a computer science student at Stanford."

Wikipedia's search is not an AI — it does not understand what "founder of Google" *means*.  It just gives you a list of pages that happen to contain the phrase that you're searching for.  That's all it's *supposed* to do.

Answer (score 1):

Try typing "who was the founder of google" [here](http://tools.wmflabs.org/bene/ask/).

In general, for semantic search use [Wikidata](https://www.wikidata.org/), not Wikipedia.